# Where can I find 'g' in level 7?

Tags: vim-adventures

I can't seem to find the *g* button in the *emptyStr*. Am I missing something obvious? I reached the end of the level already but the girl says that I need to go back and find *g*.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is stupid, but after getting a response from the author I realised I've missed `g` at the beginning of the level. Interesting that I actually finished it anyway.

> The 'g' button is in the house in the beginning of the level, right
>   above the Alice quote. Make sure you have a yellow key to open the
>   door.